# Direction of Webkit rotation-transform?

Tags: webkit, rotation, transform, direction

is there a way to change the direction of the webkit rotation-transform? Currently it rotates an object to the right, but I would need to rotate it to the left.

**edit:** the angle it should rotate, i parse out of a document, so it's fixed!

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate by a negative angle.

Comment: Add a `-` in front of the parsed angle.

Comment: If it starts with a `-`, remove the `-`.  Alternatively, parse it as an int, then negate it.